# importing vcf file to org document

Tags: org-mode

I create vcf files for all my clients. At times, I am required to include their Surname name \ DOB \ Phone number in the org document. Is their any way I can import the data directly from vcf file. ?

Comment: As it's a text file you can simply parse all the fields. What's the problem?

Comment: I am not a programmer. I do not know how to parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this package](https://github.com/flexibeast/org-vcard) to
convert `*.vcf` into an `*.org` document. You can install it either by
using `package-install` or by downloading [this
file](https://github.com/flexibeast/org-vcard/blob/master/org-vcard.el)
and evaluating it manually with `eval-buffer`. Next run
<kbd>M</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> `org-vcard-import`. You will be asked for
`Source:`, just type `file` here and press <kbd>Return</kbd>. You will
be asked for `Destination`, also type just `file` and press
<kbd>Return</kbd>. Next thing you will be asked for is a path to an
input `.vcf` file and finally you will be asked for a path to an
output `.org` file. Output `.org` file will contain entries in the
following format:

```
* Name LastName
:PROPERTIES:
:VERSION: 3.0
:N: LastName;Name;;;
:EMAIL: email@example.com
:CELL: (xxx) xxx-xxx
:END:
```